# Priority queue in python get the value

Tags: python, priority-queue

I'm new here.
I use a priority'queue 'that is instantiated randomly with two types of arrival and departure events, as you can see in the code. I need to check the lowest generated value and check if it is associated with an 'A' or a 'D', using'queue.get 'is not giving.

```
class PriorityQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([str(i) for i in self.queue])

        # for checking if the queue is empty

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.queue) == []

        # for inserting an element in the queue

    def insert(self, data):
        self.queue.append(data)

        # for popping an element based on Priority

    def delete(self):
        try:
            max = 0
            for i in range(len(self.queue)):
                if self.queue[i] < self.queue[max]:
                    max = i
            item = self.queue[max]
            del self.queue[max]
            return item
        except IndexError:
            print()
            exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':


    queue = PriorityQueue()

    Arrival = int(random.expovariate(1/15))
    Departure = randint(15, 45)

    queue.insert((Arrival, 'A'))
    queue.insert((Departure, 'D'))

    Arrival = int(random.expovariate(1/15))
    Departure = randint(15, 45)

    queue.insert((Arrival, 'A'))
    queue.insert((Departure, 'D'))

    Arrival = int(random.expovariate(1/15))
    Departure = randint(15, 45)

    queue.insert((Arrival, 'A'))
    queue.insert((Departure, 'D'))

    Arrival = int(random.expovariate(1/15))
    Departure = randint(15, 45)

    queue.insert((Arrival, 'A'))
    queue.insert((Departure, 'D'))

    Arrival = int(random.expovariate(1/15))
    Departure = randint(15, 45)

    queue.insert((Arrival, 'A'))
    queue.insert((Departure, 'D'))

    print(queue)

    while not queue.isEmpty():
        print(queue.delete())

    queue = Variaveis()
```

I should at the end print with the help of a'if 'the value of A and D in ascending order.

Comment: Does the code you posted run? It doesn't for me - ZeroDivisionErrors and undefined `Variaveis`

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your question.

Why would you make it necessary to import random and from random import randint?
Since you just use 2 functions from random module you could

```
 from random import randint, expovariate
```

As noted

```
queue = Variaveis()
```

throws an error so I ignored it, as it doesn't seem to matter in this context.

An example result is:

```
(0, 'A') (43, 'D') (3, 'A') (40, 'D') (8, 'A') (15, 'D') (7, 'A') (26, 'D') (15, 'A') (25, 'D')
(0, 'A')
(3, 'A')
(7, 'A')
(8, 'A')
(15, 'A')
(15, 'D')
(25, 'D')
(26, 'D')
(40, 'D')
(43, 'D')
```

The first line excluded the list is obviously sorted by the highest value in a pair.
If you want to match A and D I recommend

```
queue.insert((Arrival, 'A'), (Departure, 'D'))
```

I also recommend having a look at the list.sort() functions and other useful list operations [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).